# Image not showing up while binding using ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a control to which i need to bind a instances of following object. However the image is not showing up in the control. please tell me what am i doing wrong.

```
   public class DataNeeded
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Image AdImage { get; set; }




    }


 private  AdsCollection strs = new AdsCollection();

    public AdsCollection ImagePaths
    {
        get
        {
            DataNeeded dataNeed=new DataNeeded();
            dataNeed.Name = "Banner1";
            Image adimage = new Image();
            adimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"G:\adimages\pngs\banner1.png"));
            dataNeed.AdImage = adimage;
            strs.Add(dataNeed);

            DataNeeded dataNeed2 = new DataNeeded();
            dataNeed2.Name = "Banner2";
            Image adimage2 = new Image();
            adimage2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"G:\adimages\pngs\banner2.png"));
            dataNeed2.AdImage = adimage2;
            strs.Add(dataNeed2);

            DataNeeded dataNeed3 = new DataNeeded();
            dataNeed3.Name = "Banner3";
            Image adimage3 = new Image();
            adimage3.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"G:\adimages\pngs\banner2.png"));
            dataNeed3.AdImage = adimage3;
            strs.Add(dataNeed3);

            //strs.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"G:\adimages\pngs\banner2.png")));
            //strs.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"G:\adimages\pngs\banner3.png")));
            //strs.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"G:\adimages\pngs\banner4.png")));

            return strs;

        }
```

The xaml for the control is as follows

```
<telerik:RadTransitionControl   x:Name="radControl" adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.ItemChangeDelay="0:0:3" 
                                  adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.CurrentSelectedIndex="0"
                              adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.IndexChanged="{Binding TopItemCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                              adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ImagePaths}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="650">
        <telerik:RadTransitionControl.Transition>
            <telerik:MotionBlurredZoomTransition />
        </telerik:RadTransitionControl.Transition>

    <telerik:RadTransitionControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=AdImage}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTransitionControl.ContentTemplate>

</telerik:RadTransitionControl>
```

Comment: Are you binding to a System.Windows.Controls.Image or a System.Drawing.Image?

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I can see that you have Image controls in your ViewModel object and you bind an Image control in the ContentTemplate to the Image control from your data object which is not correct. You could either replace the Image control from the contentTemplate with a ContentPresenter (it can display Image controls), to bind the Image control in the Source property of the Image from the data object or to change the data object entirely.

In my opinion the best solution is to change the DataNeeded class as follows:

```
public class DataNeeded
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource AdImage { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.